# Estimating variance when only the estimates are available

Tags: variance, generalized-linear-model

Suppose you have a large set of estimates (predictors) presumably created with a generalized linear model (GLM) with gamma error and an inverse link (possibly a log link).  You know that there are 3 variables used in the model: state, type, and territory (zip code groups).  You do not know the betas (*i.e.*, estimated coefficients); you can only estimate them by comparing the estimates.  For example, the prediction for territory 1 in a particular state is $x\%$ different from territory 2, so there is a beta that creates that difference in the output.

Is there a way--via simulation, closed form, or whatever--to create a bound for the variance of each estimate?

I know this is a very strange question, but this does have useful practical applications and your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

**The question again condensed:**  You have estimates from a GLM with gamma error and inverse link.  You know the estimates vary by state, type and territory.   Can you estimate or find an outer bound for the variance of each estimate using any technique you can conjure up?